# Division free subset of maximum cardinality

Tags: algorithm

A set S of positive integers is said to be “division free” if there do not exist distinct elements x and y of S such that x is divisible by y. For example, S = { 2, 3, 5 } is division free, but { 2, 3, 4, 5 } is not, since 4 is divisible by 2. How would you compute a maximum subset of { 1, 2, ..., n } that is division free? For example, when n = 10, then T = { 4, 6, 7, 9, 10 } is one of the maximum division free subsets.

My nephew in elementary school asked me this seemingly simple math problem. I can only think of brute force method. But it gets ugly when n is large. Is there a decent algorithm to solve it by computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Two numbers `k` and `2k` couldn't belong to division-free subset simultaneously, so the subset can't consist of more than `ceil(n/2)` numbers.
Simply take all numbers from `floor(n/2)+1` to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

This is same as finding an independent set in a [comparability graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph), which has polynomial time algorithms, as it is a perfect graph.

Check out this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/how-to-find-the-maximum-independent-set-of-a-directed-graph

Comment: Ok. I misread. This is a famous and well known math problem (specific set: {1,2,...n}). Not a programming problem, with an arbitrary set of integers, to which my answer is applicable.